# Exception while running pyspark sql query

Tags: pyspark, amazon-emr

I'm new to pyspark and trying to run some basic flows.
This code below fails with an exception and I could not find any suggested solution, it runs on an AWS EMR from local Pycharm as a remote interpreter. The spark version is 3.3.1.

Code :

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("location_temp.csv")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("location_temp")
data = spark.sql("select * from location_temp")
```

And the exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/pycharm_project_174/app/application_2.py", line 99, in <module>
    main()
  File "/tmp/pycharm_project_174/app/application_2.py", line 62, in main
    data = spark.sql("select * from location_temp")
  File "/home/hadoop/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 1440, in sql
    return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery, litArgs), self)
  File "/home/hadoop/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1323, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/home/hadoop/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/errors/exceptions/captured.py", line 169, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/hadoop/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 332, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name, value))
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o61.sql. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method sql([class java.lang.String, class java.util.HashMap]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:274)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

Any suggestion ?
Thanks

Comment: Are there MapType columns/dictionaries in `location_temp.csv` file?

Comment: no, the columns are date and string type.

Comment: can you show us how the first few rows of the data looks like ?